# Name and then sort a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range that length keeps changing.  I need to redefine the named range each time it changes and then sort it.

I have this so far:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Name and Sort
'
    Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="data4", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "='Data Storage'!R3C1:R25C18"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("data4").Comment = ""
    Application.Goto Reference:="data4"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Storage").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Storage").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "D3:D25"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Storage").sort
        .SetRange Range("A3:R25")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

But the next time the range changes it only sorts on the previous range.  I think it has to do with the R3C1:R25C18 reference but I don't know how to change that each time the range changes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do the columns change every time too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks for the last row with data, names the range, and sorts the named range

```
Dim lngRowLast As Long

'Find last row
lngRowLast = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Your range goes here
Range(cells(3,1),cells(lngRowLast,18)).Name = "data4" 

Range("data4").Sort Key1:=Cells(3, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Thanks Jason,what does Cells.Find(What:-"*" do?

Comment: In this example, it finds the last row with data in the active worksheet.  It can also be used to find the last column by replacing the SearchOrder to xlByColumns and the ending syntax from .Row to .Column

Comment: great thanks - If I want to sort by col 4 would I change Key1:(1,1) to Key1(1,4) ?

Comment: Yes, Key1:=cells(1,4) would sort column 4 first.  
If you wanted more than one sort, you could add Key2:=cells(1,2) if you wanted to sort by column 2 as a second sort, you would need to add Order2:=xlAscending if you wanted it to be ascending and Order2:=xlDescending if you wanted it to be Descending order

Comment: I got an error when sorting.  It is only identifying the first column in the range.  The range has to be to the end of the first row and the last column

Comment: I edited the code above to reflect the fix.  Does the edited code work?

Comment: Sub Macro2() ' ' Name and Sort 
Dim lngRowLast As Long 
'Find last row 
lngRowLast = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 
'Your range goes here 
Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lngRowLast, 1)).Name = "data" Range(cells(3,1),cells(lngRowLast,18)).Name = "data" Range("data").Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 3), Order1:=xlAscending, _ Header:=xlYes End Sub

Comment: If you copy the edited code above, does it work?  I made an edit.